# Where can I get a list of cache line sizes and cache sizes for AMD and Intel processors

Tags: caching

I was hoping somebody somewhere has compiled a human readable list of L1 cache size / line size for recent processors.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're looking for, but there's the [CPUID](http://www.cpuid-pro.com/index.php) dev kits which can determine this info programmatically.